# How to resolve stopwords error in Rake along with many more?

Tags: python, pycharm, rake

"D:\Python files\venv\Scripts\python.exe" "D:/Python files/main.py"
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "D:\Python files\venv\lib\site-packages\nltk\corpus\util.py", line 84, in __load
root = nltk.data.find(f"{self.subdir}/{zip_name}")
File "D:\Python files\venv\lib\site-packages\nltk\data.py", line 583, in find
raise LookupError(resource_not_found)
LookupError:

---

Resource stopwords not found.
Please use the NLTK Downloader to obtain the resource:

> > > import nltk
> > > nltk.download('stopwords')

For more information see: https://www.nltk.org/data.html

Attempted to load corpora/stopwords.zip/stopwords/

Searched in:
- 'C:\Users\Harsh/nltk_data'
- 'D:\Python files\venv\nltk_data'
- 'D:\Python files\venv\share\nltk_data'
- 'D:\Python files\venv\lib\nltk_data'
- 'C:\Users\Harsh\AppData\Roaming\nltk_data'
- 'C:\nltk_data'
- 'D:\nltk_data'
- 'E:\nltk_data'

---

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "D:\Python files\main.py", line 16, in 
r = Rake()
File "D:\Python files\venv\lib\site-packages\rake_nltk\rake.py", line 84, in **init**
self.stopwords = set(nltk.corpus.stopwords.words(language))
File "D:\Python files\venv\lib\site-packages\nltk\corpus\util.py", line 121, in **getattr**
self.__load()
File "D:\Python files\venv\lib\site-packages\nltk\corpus\util.py", line 86, in __load
raise e
File "D:\Python files\venv\lib\site-packages\nltk\corpus\util.py", line 81, in __load
root = nltk.data.find(f"{self.subdir}/{self.__name}")
File "D:\Python files\venv\lib\site-packages\nltk\data.py", line 583, in find
raise LookupError(resource_not_found)
LookupError:

---

Resource stopwords not found.
Please use the NLTK Downloader to obtain the resource:

> > > import nltk
> > > nltk.download('stopwords')

For more information see: https://www.nltk.org/data.html

Attempted to load corpora/stopwords

Searched in:
- 'C:\Users\Harsh/nltk_data'
- 'D:\Python files\venv\nltk_data'
- 'D:\Python files\venv\share\nltk_data'
- 'D:\Python files\venv\lib\nltk_data'
- 'C:\Users\Harsh\AppData\Roaming\nltk_data'
- 'C:\nltk_data'
- 'D:\nltk_data'
- 'E:\nltk_data'

---

Process finished with exit code 1

tried cahnging code, reslving syntax errrors expecting solution

Comment: What code? Which syntax errors? What is your question? It is kind of hard to fulfil expectations, when there is nothing to operate on.

Comment: actually i was following a tutorial from youtube that how to use RAKE to extract specific keywords from a text file so i did same as the tutorial but my code is showing error in the run terminal in py charm

Comment: i have given the error that is showing in the terminal.

Comment: Yes, I can see that these are tracebacks. But you have not posted any code, that creates these errors. How can we understand, where these errors come from, when there is no code in your question?!? And please post a minimum verifiable example MVE of your code: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

you will solve it by running this code in your python IDE

```
import nltk
import ssl

try:
    _create_unverified_https_context = ssl._create_unverified_context
except AttributeError:
    pass
else:
    ssl._create_default_https_context = _create_unverified_https_context

nltk.download()
```

after this, it should open a window which will allow you to select the **nltk** resources you want to use. It should be like this:[image]

Then you click on "**Download**" and you should be ready to go!